# Why must all of the sublevel sets of a real, continuous function  in Rn, where ()→ +∞ as ‖‖→+∞, be compact?

Tags: convex-optimization

I was reviewing the answer to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926878/when-are-sublevel-sets-of-convex-subdifferentiable-functions-bounded/2927247#2927247?newreg=0dc88ab66e11445b8adc448fc631cd56) and am trying to understand why condition 3 holds. That is: why does a real, continuous function  in $\mathbb{R}^n $, where ()→ +∞ as ‖‖→+∞, have compact sublevel sets?

I can picture sublevel sets in a 2D plane, but I think I am getting confused when trying to interpret them in a higher dimension.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you understand what “$f(x) \to +\infty$ as $\Vert x \Vert \to +\infty$” means?

Comment: I'm thinking about it geometrically, so as the length of my vector gets larger and larger (going to infinity), my function is also going to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

A sublevel set $f^{-1}[(-\infty,c]]$ is closed since $f$ is continuous and $(-\infty,c]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

The condition that $\lim\limits_{\lVert x\rVert\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ enforces that $f^{-1}[(-\infty,c]]$ is bounded for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (think about what happens if $f^{-1}[(-\infty,c]]$ is unbounded for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$).

Since every sublevel set is closed and bounded, then by the Heine-Borel theorem, they are compact.